# Plone calendar invalid argument for year less then 1970

Tags: plone

We have recently upgraded our site to plone 4 and noticed our calender picker doesnt work if date is older then 1970. After small debugging, noticed this line is issue

```
plone.app.form.widgets.datecomponents.py -> result method
```

for date less then 1970 `date.timeTime` result negative value and localtime method expecting positive value I assume.

```
local_zone = date.localZone(localtime(date.timeTime()))
```

Any help, idea or suggestion is always good

Here is traceback

```
Traceback (innermost last):
  Module ZPublisher.Publish, line 126, in publish
  Module ZPublisher.mapply, line 77, in mapply
  Module ZPublisher.Publish, line 46, in call_object
  Module Products.CMFFormController.ControllerPageTemplate, line 75, in __call__
  Module Products.CMFFormController.BaseControllerPageTemplate, line 31, in _call
  Module Shared.DC.Scripts.Bindings, line 322, in __call__
  Module Shared.DC.Scripts.Bindings, line 359, in _bindAndExec
  Module Products.PageTemplates.ZopePageTemplate, line 334, in _exec
  Module Products.PageTemplates.ZopePageTemplate, line 431, in pt_render
  Module Products.PageTemplates.PageTemplate, line 79, in pt_render
  Module zope.pagetemplate.pagetemplate, line 113, in pt_render
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 271, in __call__
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 343, in interpret
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 888, in do_useMacro
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 343, in interpret
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 533, in do_optTag_tal
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 518, in do_optTag
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 513, in no_tag
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 343, in interpret
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 954, in do_defineSlot
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 343, in interpret
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 533, in do_optTag_tal
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 518, in do_optTag
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 513, in no_tag
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 343, in interpret
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 858, in do_defineMacro
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 343, in interpret
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 954, in do_defineSlot
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 343, in interpret
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 533, in do_optTag_tal
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 518, in do_optTag
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 513, in no_tag
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 343, in interpret
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 946, in do_defineSlot
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 343, in interpret
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 533, in do_optTag_tal
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 518, in do_optTag
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 513, in no_tag
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 343, in interpret
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 821, in do_loop_tal
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 343, in interpret
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 533, in do_optTag_tal
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 518, in do_optTag
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 513, in no_tag
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 343, in interpret
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 888, in do_useMacro
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 343, in interpret
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 583, in do_setLocal_tal
  Module zope.tales.tales, line 696, in evaluate
   - URL: calendar_macros
   - Line 12, Column 4
   - Expression: <PythonExpr date_components_support_view.result(inputvalue, 0, starting_year, ending_year, future_years)>
   - Names:
      {'container': <ATFolder at /rcseng/account>,
       'context': <ATFolder at /rcseng/account>,
       'default': <object object at 0x01DE1830>,
       'here': <ATFolder at /rcseng/account>,
       'loop': {u'record': <Products.PageTemplates.Expressions.PathIterator object at 0x0E0BEAB0>},
       'nothing': None,
       'options': {'args': (),
                   'state': <Products.CMFFormController.ControllerState.ControllerState object at 0x0E287F30>},
       'repeat': <Products.PageTemplates.Expressions.SafeMapping object at 0x0E21E810>,
       'request': <HTTPRequest, URL=http://dev.rcseng.ac.uk/account/my_details>,
       'root': <Application at >,
       'template': <ControllerPageTemplate at /rcseng/account/my_details>,
       'traverse_subpath': [],
       'user': <PloneUser '227225'>}
  Module Products.PageTemplates.ZRPythonExpr, line 48, in __call__
   - __traceback_info__: date_components_support_view.result(inputvalue, 0, starting_year, ending_year, future_years)
  Module PythonExpr, line 1, in <expression>
  Module plone.app.form.widgets.datecomponents, line 97, in result
ValueError: (22, 'Invalid argument')
```

Comment: i used http://svn.plone.org/svn/archetypes/MoreFieldsAndWidgets/MxDateTimeField/ in a plone2.5 project some years ago to store dates before 1970.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having investigated this further, could indeed reproduce the problems you report. I was able to enter pre-epoch (January 1st, 1970) dates just fine on most platforms *except* Windows.

It is indeed so that Zope's DateTime instances use negative second values for timestamps before the epoch, but Python's `time.localtime` can *usually* deal with negative values just fine:

```
>>> import time
>>> time.localtime(-10000)
time.struct_time(tm_year=1969, tm_mon=12, tm_mday=31, tm_hour=22, tm_min=13, tm_sec=20, tm_wday=2, tm_yday=365, tm_isdst=0)
```

I've tested this across several python 2.x releases on Mac, FreeBSD and Linux. When you test this on Windows however, you indeed get a ValueError. Note that this is a problem across the python and Plone versions, this is a Windows-specific problem!

The code in question is trying to determine the local timezone for the given date, which could be either summer time (daylight saving time) or winter time. So, on Windows, we can also swap out the year in the date to the current year, for this calculation to work. It *potentially* could get DST calculations wrong, depending on the exact local timezone, but since you cannot get the correct calculation for pre-1970 dates *anyway*, this is a good compromise.

I've committed the following replacement for line 97 to git just now ([commit 63b043a7ba](https://github.com/plone/plone.app.form/commit/63b043a7ba779116995757557254665efa531123)):

```
try:
    local_zone = date.localZone(localtime(date.timeTime()))
except ValueError:
    # Dates before 1970 use a negative timeTime() value, which on
    # on some platforms are not handled well and lead to a ValueError.
    # In those cases, calculate the local timezone (which is DST based)
    # from the same date in the *current year* instead. This is better
    # than failing altogether!
    timeZoneDate = DateTime(localtime().tm_year, *date.parts()[1:])
    local_zone = date.localZone(localtime(timeZoneDate.timeTime()))
```

Use this in your local egg, or wait for a new release of the 2.1 branch of the package.

Comment: Hmm. I wonder how we are storing all those birthdays.... DateTime surely should be able to deal with pre-1970 years.

Comment: A matter of different constructions? You can present a date but no time?

Comment: There is no issue with datetime. it handles dates before 1970. its timeTime method which return negative seconds which localtime method doesnt like it.

Comment: No, I am wrong indeed, internally it uses negative values for the number of seconds since the epoch. Will update in a bit when I have some time.

Comment: Updated the answer, Windows `time.localtime()` cannot handle negative values, other platforms can.

Comment: Thanks Martijn for your time and effort. I will roll this on Monday morning... happy weekend...